# NetSuite Order Pick Ticket Printing

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to determine when a sales order is loaded for printing if it is having a pick ticket printed. The only event triggered is the BeforeLoad user event...

```
/**
 * The recordType (internal id) corresponds to the "Applied To" record in your script deployment. 
 * @appliedtorecord recordType
 *   
 * @param {String} type Operation types: create, edit, view, copy, print, email
 * @param {nlobjForm} form Current form
 * @param {nlobjRequest} request Request object
 * @returns {Void}
 */
function userEventBeforeLoad(type, form, request) {
    if (type == "print") {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

The "request" parameter passed in by the system is empty, I've tried pulling session objects from the script context, and I have nothing that helps. I don't know if I'm overlooking something that isn't obvious or recorded somewhere.

I know that the system has the "printedpickticket" search filter, but for some reason it doesn't always get flagged. So, orders that have had pick tickets printed don't get marked, and then when trying to perform actions on orders that have had their pick tickets printed, not all orders are retrieved.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem. I don't have a solution, but I found a workaround that will do the job for us.

As you pointed out, the system passes nlobjForm to the function as the 2nd argument. form contains another object called tabs. form.tabs (at least on our implementation) gets a different set of data when a pick ticket is printed as compared to when the transaction is being printed. I'm using form.tabs[1]=='address' in my case to indicate Pick Ticket.

I'm still hunting for something better to key off of, but this is working reliably for now. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: This is great, I used the tabs to differentiate between the two. Used it to create some auditing on the sales order record about how many times the record had been printed, who printed it, and date/time... awesome workaround :)

Answer (score 0):

The 'Printed Picking Ticket' field resets to 'F' when an Item Fulfillment is created, if there is anything left to fulfill on the Sales Order.  Not sure if this is your issue, but it's the only thing that comes to mind.  If it is, and you still need to perform actions on those partially fulfilled orders, you could check the System Notes to see if that field has ever been set to 'T'.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, that's not the case. These orders haven't yet had any fulfillments. They're new orders with a pick ticket printed within a half hour and no other actions taken. That's why I'm trying to find some sort of indicator when the "print" operator is passed into the BeforeLoad event handler.

Answer (score 0):

On Sales Order/Transfer Order record, when a user prints the record via Print Picking Ticket option, the log Printed Picking Ticket in System Notes is set from "F" to "T". 
Hope this will help.you can get the trigger from system Note